# Discord Python installation

Tags: python, discord.py

I started trying to code Discord Bot. But in VS Code terminal I type `pip install discord` it says

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ pip install discord
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed on your system ?

Comment: how do i install pip tho?

Answer (score -3):

just don't go to the terminal in your python file type "import discord" run the file and Discord.py will install